# How to improve into vim of MacOS Mojave the speed of vertical scroll with bottom/up keys?

Tags: vim, scroll, macvim

I have a new MacBook with Mojave and vim already installed.

Unfortunately, even for small source files, the cursor is very fast when I browse the current part of file where I am located but it becomes very slow when I am over this current page (the same thing occurs if I am over or lower this part) with down/up keys.

I don't talk about "mouse scrolling speed" but scrolling with down/up keys.

I saw and tried to apply different suggested solutions on web but none of these work for me (disable `cursorline`, using an empty `~/.vimrc` , etc ...).

Maybe there is a conflict with some options in my `~/.vimrc`. Here below my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
set ic
command Il :%s/^/\=line('.'). ' '
set hlsearch
set shiftwidth=2        " number of spaces to use for auto indent
set autoindent          " copy indent from current line when starting a new line
set nu
syntax on               " syntax highlighting
set backspace=indent,eol,start " delete with backspace 
"TOhtml
let html_use_css=1
let html_number_lines=1
let html_no_pre=0
highlight DiffAdd    cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffDelete cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffChange cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=17 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
highlight DiffText   cterm=bold ctermfg=10 ctermbg=88 gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
```

I have changed into `System Preferences` the delay between 2 repeated keys to a small value :

So, into the default Terminal of Mojave MacBook, I can move quickly with left/right keys on the command line.

Is there a relation between this small delay I have set and this slow scroll vertically with down/up keys into vim ?

Comment: By bottom/up keys do you mean the arrow keys (down and up)? A screencast may help to understand the behavior you describe.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, this is what I wanted to mean. For example, in the text editor here on StackOverflow, it is very fast horizontally and vertically. Into the vim editor on my MacOS Mojave, it is fast horizontally but too much slow vertically, it is frustrating...